# How does one write a method to call after a variable or object, such as "string {0}".format(stringy)?

Tags: python, python-module

For different data types, like string, there are methods that you call by adding a dot after, such as:

```
"string {0}".format(stringy)
```

or

```
listx.remove(x)
```

How is the information being passed to the method? How can I write a function like that?

Comment: this is a core concept in python, you can read any tutorial about creating objects/custom classes

Comment: Welcome to the world of object-oriented programming!

Answer (score 2):

```
class YourObject(object):
   def do_something(self):
      print('doing something')
```

Then you can use your object:

```
your_object = YourObject()
your_object.do_something()
```

This shows how to create an object, and call a method on it (like theexamples you provided in your post).

There are way more in-depth tutorials/blogs about object creation and custom classes.  A good place to start is always the [standard documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html).

Answer (score 2):

You can create a custom [`class`](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html) and then include whatever methods you want.  Below is an example:

```
>>> class MyClass(object):         # Define class MyClass
...     def __init__(self):        # Define MyClass' constructor method
...         self.name = "Me"       # Make an attribute
...     def getName(self):         # Define method getName
...         return self.name       # Return MyClass' attribute name (self.name)
...
>>> test = MyClass()               # Initialize (create an instance of) MyClass
>>> print test.getName()           # Print the name attribute by calling the getName method
Me
>>>
```

Basically, you are working with OOP (Object-Oriented Programming).  However, since this concept is so large, I can't demonstrate/explain everything you can do with it here (otherwise my post would be enormous).  My advice is to research OOP and Python classes.  There are many good tutorials you can find.  I gave one above; [here](https://thenewcircle.com/bookshelf/python_fundamentals_tutorial/oop.html) is another: